# "INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE" during installing of system service apk

Tags: wso2, android-install-apk

To build package "org.wso2.emm.system.service", I build the APK from https://github.com/wso2/product-emm (folder: modules/mobile-agents/android/system-service) with AndroidStudio, SDK 23.

The build compilation passed, I get the apk, and want install it on my non-rooted device (Galaxy Tab A6 2016) on Android 6.0.1.

Here I typed to install the apk:

```
$ sudo adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 0e9850346394-android

$ sudo adb devices -l
List of devices attached
52036e4ff4229373       device usb:1-1 product:gtaxlltexx model:SM_T585 device:gtaxllte

$ sudo adb install system-service/app/system-service-release.apk 
[100%] /data/local/tmp/system-service-release.apk
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/system-service-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]
$
```

So, I have 2 questions:

- Does the devices must be rooted ?
- If the device is rooted, that will not cause issue for the agent package (org.wso2.emm.agent) ?

Thanks a lot for your futures replies.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: No sorry, we didn't found a solution, we didn't use WSO2 anymore :'( .

Comment: This is likely due to the APK using **android:sharedUserId** in its AndroidManifest...